# What is Stack Exchange's position on stackanswers.net (Askru)

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

https://stackanswers.net seems like a shameless copy of Stack Overflow. I could not find any good information about the site and it looks to be everything but legitimate. Is the Stack Exchange team aware of this site and allowing it to copy site content?

Or perhaps is there nothing one can do about such sites?

Comment: This specific site has not been asked about here before, and I was completely unaware that this is a common problem. I also had no knowledge of "site scraping" so downvotes feel unjustified. Nevertheless, I have now reported the site because of lack of attribution. You are welcome, StackExchange.

Comment: Note that here on Meta Stack Exchange, we close questions as duplicates of questions tagged [tag:faq] if the answer to that question also addresses this question, even though the questions themselves may not be exactly the same. This is to link users to the canonical posts regarding topics. See [this section of our FAQ on how Meta Stack Exchange works](/a/47635/377214) and the last section of [our FAQ on duplicate closures](/a/10844/377214).